# Can I trigger LogAnalytics to send an email containing the error itself each time an error is written?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

At our company we are discussing how to approach logging, in a general, generic way. We have multiple Azure subscriptions for multiple customers.

My vision:
Log everything to Log Analytics and send notifications when bad things happen. My idea can easily be described (in pseudo) as this:

```
if (level = "Error")
 { SendMailToActionGroup(ErrorBody); }
```

So, is this doable?

**Can I trigger LogAnalytics to send an email containing the error itself each time an error is written?**

At this point I've figured out how to find errors in Log Analytics by doing a log search, for example this one:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Level == "Error"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
```

I run it every five minute and sure, it finds some stuff. It then calls the decided Action group and sends an e-mail that states that the alarm has been triggered. The threshold is 1 hit.

But this is not enough. Those emails sent from Azure goes directly to our customer-wide service portal. This is where we need the error, not the information that an alert has been triggered. Sometimes multiple errors occur and the email does not explain them all. It shows top 1 search result, and some basic stuff.

So, a better way to face this would be to catch all errors as they're being written to Log Analytics. Then we can catch them separately, and initiate  a case on each and every one of them, based on an e-mail that already contains all necessary information.

Please feel free to improve the question since I haven't found anything else regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it’s a good point! AFAIK the alert mail format is as per design. If you are looking for a dynamic mail format while creating alert then please feel free to provide feedback in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics.

Workaround could be to follow https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/fca567e3bc4b47398fa9580e7ea25614/receive-monitoring-alert-emails-based-on-azure-kusto-telemetry/

And I would change the vision (in pseudo) for AzureDiagnostics logs as shown below.

```
if (Level = "Error") {
ConfigureMailBodyWithLogicAppOrFunctionAppOrRunbook (Level,ResultDescription,ResultType,Status,TimeGenerated,ErrorCode,ErrorMessage, etc.);
ConfigureAlertWithActionGroupEitherLogicAppOrFunctionAppOrRunbookActionType();
}
```

So instead of having ‘email’ as action type, you may go with action types logic app or function app or runbook and try to have the dynamic mail body formatted inside them. For help please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups-logic-app

OR in another easier way, you may try to have the query in more granular way to fetch patterned error and then create alert for it accordingly. For example, to get an alert email if any SQL service is stopped then use below query.

```
Event
| where (EventLog == "System")
| where (RenderedDescription has "sql" and RenderedDescription has "stopped")
```

For example that is related to AzureDiagnostics logs for your service area, you may check if any AzureDiagnostics property has in detail description of error and then have the query with those properties. The list of all possible properties for AzureDiagnostics logs is listed in the section named ‘service-specific schemas for resource diagnostic logs’ here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/tutorial-dashboards .Hope it helps!!

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, and yes - this definitely helps :) This is probably the best way to approach this at the moment. Thanks alot!